# tf.data - get labels from shuffled dataset without shuffle

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I need to get labels from validation dataset for construct the confusion matrix, but I can't get labels with normal order without recreating the dataset with disabled the shuffle. Any idea?
Probably, there are any ways to get prediction together with labels? (how is, model.evaluate() works with shuffle)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the answer: [Getting true labels for keras predictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812921/getting-true-labels-for-keras-predictions)

```
for images, labels in val_ds:
    preds = model.predict(images)
    acc_sc = acc(labels, tf.argmax(preds, axis=1))
    print(acc_sc)
    break # or accumulate and average score from all batches
```

But probably a better way is exist?

Comment: That's still shuffled

Comment: yes, but you can calculate accuracy from each batch and average it.

Comment: that doesn't answer the title of your question, and if your answer is the same as the other question, your question will be closed as duplicate